# Error Exception: Undefined variable: categories

Tags: laravel

I pretty new to Laravel 7, I have been learning the framework at the same time trying to create a system. I am stuck on Undefined variable error were create a form called create inside equipment folder it has several fields. I want to pull data from the db table called equipcat and display it on select tag. If use {{form}} method it works but the below method fails, i prefer to use the below method instead of {{form}}

create.blade.php

```
 <select class="form-control input-sm" id="category_name" name="category_name">
      <option value="">--Choose Category--</option>
      @foreach ($categories as $row)
     <option>{{$row->name}}</option>                    
 @endforeach                     
</select>
```

CategoryController:

```
$categories = DB::table('equipcat')->pluck("name","cat_id");
return view('equipment.create',compact('categories'));
```

Web.app

```
Route::get('equipment.create', 'CategoryController@getcategory');
```

[image: Controller]

[image: CategoryModel]

[image: create.blade]

[image: route]

[image: error msg]

Comment: welcome to SO ... i think you should put screen shot as your new

Comment: perhaps there is another action that is returning this view and it is not passing the `categories`?

Comment: I have uploaded my screenshots @Kamlesh Paul

Answer (score 1):

you can use "select" instead of "pluck"

```
    $data = DB::table('equipcat')->select('name','cat_id')->get();
```

try this hope it help

Answer (score 1):

```
I found a solution. In my create.blade.php I added this line @php($categories=\App\Category::all()) to declared the variable and it worked. my create.blade.php looks like this:



@php($categories=\App\Category::all())
  @foreache($categories as $row)
  <option value="">{{ $row->name }}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is use model for querying. Change your CategoryController to:

```
$categories = Category::select("name","cat_id")->get();
return view('equipment.create',compact('categories'));
```

I hope you have model of Category.

Comment: Yes i do, i will give this a shot. Thank you